# Problems preloading audio in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to make a cross-device/browser image and audio preloading scheme for a GameAPI I'm working on. An audio file will preload, and issue a callback once it completes.

The problem is, audio will not start to load on slow page loads, but will usually work on the second try, probably because it cached it and knows it exists.

I've narrowed it down to the audio.load() function. Getting rid of it solves the problem, but interestingly, my motorola droid needs that function.

What are some experiences you've had with HTML5 audio preloading?

Here's my code. Yes, I know loading images in a separate function could cause a race condition :)

```
var resourcesLoading = 0;

function loadImage(imgSrc) {
    //alert("Starting to load an image");
    resourcesLoading++;

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imgSrc;

    image.onload = function() {
        //CODE GOES HERE
        //alert("A image has been loaded");
        resourcesLoading--;
        onResourceLoad();
    }
}

function loadSound(soundSrc) {
    //alert("Starting to load a sound");
    resourcesLoading++;

    var loaded = false;

    //var soundFile = document.createElement("audio");
    var soundFile = document.createElement("audio");
    console.log(soundFile);
    soundFile.autoplay = false;
    soundFile.preload = false;

    var src = document.createElement("source");
    src.src = soundSrc + ".mp3";
    soundFile.appendChild(src);

    function onLoad() {
        loaded = true;

        soundFile.removeEventListener("canplaythrough", onLoad, true);
        soundFile.removeEventListener("error", onError, true);

        //CODE GOES HERE
        //alert("A sound has been loaded");
        resourcesLoading--;
        onResourceLoad();
    }

    //Attempt to reload the resource 5 times
    var retrys = 4;

    function onError(e) {
        retrys--;

        if(retrys > 0) {
            soundFile.load();
        } else {
            loaded = true;

            soundFile.removeEventListener("canplaythrough", onLoad, true);
            soundFile.removeEventListener("error", onError, true);

            alert("A sound has failed to loaded");
            resourcesLoading--;
            onResourceLoad();
        }
    }

    soundFile.addEventListener("canplaythrough", onLoad, true);
    soundFile.addEventListener("error", onError, true);
}

function onResourceLoad() {
    if(resourcesLoading == 0)
        onLoaded();
}
```

It's hard to diagnose the problem because it shows no errors and only fails occasionally.

Comment: It's a bitch, but I've managed to fake it by just loading in audio as standard AJAX text requests. I know that sounds dumb but once the data's cached, it's cached and BOOM: preloaded audio. There are issues where browsers don't load more than one media stream, I had the same problem with video too, instead I just loaded the thumbnails and created the HTML5 player on the fly. I find that faking it as AJAX tricks the browser into think it's not media.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to try that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working. The solution was fairly simple actually:

Basically, it works like this:

```
channel.load();
channel.volume = 0.00000001;
channel.play();
```

If it isn't obvious, the `load` function tells browsers and devices that support it to start loading, and then the sound immediately tries to `play` with the `volume` virtually at zero. So, if the `load` function isn't enough, the fact that the sound 'needs' to be played is enough to trigger a load on all the devices I tested.

The `load` function may actually be redundant now, but based off the inconsistiency with audio implementation, it probably doesn't hurt to have it.

Edit: After testing this on Opera, Safari, Firefox, and Chrome, it looks like setting the `volume` to 0 will still preload the resource.

Comment: At least on video elements, you can actually mute them with `videoElem.mute = true` ... probably the same property exists for audio elements as well

Comment: I found that this worked, and in my case I was fading in / out between two players to make it seamless player.  I had to let the second track stay muted, then when I flipped to the second track it was loaded and played immediately.

Answer (score 2):

`canplaythrough` fires when **enough data has buffered** that it probably could play non-stop to the end if you started playing on that event.  The HTML Audio element is designed for streaming, so the file **may not have completely finished downloading** by the time this event fires.

Contrast this to images which only fire their event once they are completely downloaded.

If you navigate away from the page and the audio has not finished completely downloading, the browser probably doesn't cache it at all.  However, if it has finished completely downloading, it probably gets cached, which explains the behavior you've seen.

I'd recommend the [HTML5 AppCache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) to make sure the images and audio are certainly cached.

Comment: Thanks AshleysBrian. After doing some research, it was advised that I use canplaythrough as opposed to loadeddata, but I'll consider your second opinion. Caching isn't the main issue however; the loaded callback is not being called every once in awhile.

Answer (score 1):

The AppCache, as suggested above, might be your only solution to keep the audio cached from one browser-session to another (that's not what you asked for, right?). but keep in mind the limited amount of space, some browsers offer. Safari for instance allows the user to change this value in the settings but the default is 5MB - hardly enough to save a bunch of songs, especially if other websites that are frequented by your users use AppCache as well. Also IE <10 does not support AppCache.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Well of course IE doesn't support it :)

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I ran into the same problem recently, and my trick was to use a simple ajax request to load the file entirely once (which end into the cache), and then by loading the sound again directly from the cache and use the event binding `canplaythrough`.

Using [Buzz.js](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/) as my HTML5 audio library, my code is basically something like that:

```
var self = this;
$.get(this.file_name+".mp3", function(data) {
    self.sound = new buzz.sound(self.file_name, {formats: [ "mp3" ], preload: true});
    self.sound.bind("error", function(e) {
        console.log("Music Error: " + this.getErrorMessage());
    });
    self.sound.decreaseVolume(20);
    self.sound.bind("canplaythrough",function(){ self.onSoundLoaded(self); }); 
});
```