# HTML, JS: Does loading audio need user interaction on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, mobile, html5-audio

**Playing** audio definitely needs user interaction on mobiles but, my question is does **loading** audio also need user interaction?

If yes, what I want to do is preload the audio so when the user taps the play button, the audio can start playing faster, as it has already started loading.

Comment: to play it especially on iOS you need user click, yeah

Comment: Yes, but can I preload it and then when user clicks it starts playing?

Comment: I think you should be able to - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375903/problems-preloading-audio-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060642/preload-multiple-audio-files

Comment: Let me try and I'll get back...

Comment: OK. So the audio can be loaded using XMLHttpRequest without user interaction, and one user interaction is required to start playing. I needed to play other audios without user interaction, so changing the src attribute of the audio element works

Comment: From iOS 10 onwards you can autoplay video without user interaction as long as it's muted: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Comment: @TimWachter: Thanks for the info. However, the question was targetted towards audio rather than video. From this, it seems playing audio without user interaction would not be allowed obviously.

Comment: @Parth: True, you can get around that by using a touchmove event, but this is kinda hacky and will be disallowed in chrome 56 if I recall correctly

Answer (score 0):

User interaction need to load and play the audio or video in mobile device, Mobile device avoiding auto play on audio and video for bandwidth limitation. Sorry i cant comment that's why i post in answer.